# How can I get the response from dispatch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component which has a form where at the moment to do clic on submit button, I call a function `handleSubmit` (it is on my component), this function call an action through of `dispatch` and this action, I make a call to a service (HTTP Request).

**handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

   validateFields((err, params) => {
       if (!err) {
            const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

            let response = dispatch(actions.addDevice(params))
            console.log(response); //Response is undefined
       }
    });
}
```

**actions.addDevice**

```
function addDevice(params){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let { authentication } = getState();
        dispatch(request({}));

        service.addDevice(params, authentication.user.access_token)
            .then(
                response => {
                    if(response.status === 201) {
                        dispatch(success(response.data));
                    }
                    return response;
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            )
    }

    function request(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_REQUEST, response } }
    function success(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_SUCCESS, response } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

**service.addDevice**

```
function addDevice(params, token){
    return axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/user/add-device',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token},
        data: {
            data1: params.data1,
            data2: params.data2,
            data3: params.data3
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        return error.response;
    });
}
```

I would like to get the response in my component to be able to make validations but as the request is async, I never can get the response and only prints an undefined variable. How can I get the response sync? Or what do I need do to be able to make validations?

Comment: To use the response in your component you need to do 3 more things: Make a reducer on `ADD_DEVICE_REQUEST` to update the redux state, make a selector function to grab the variable you changed in the state, then add a prop to the component equal to the result of that selector with a `mapStateToProps` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the promise `service.addDevice`.

So you can do `return service.addDevice...` and in the `handleSubmit` you do `dispatch(...).then((data) => ...do something with the data...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
let response = dispatch(actions.addDevice(params))
```

this is asynchronous. So it is not surprising to return undefined from console.log(). console.log() execute even before dispatch process is completed. Use promise or async await syntax. I would recommend using the async-await syntax.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

   validateFields(async (err, params) => {
       if (!err) {
            const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

            let response =await dispatch(actions.addDevice(params))
            console.log(response); //Response is undefined
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with this code

**handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   const { validateFields } = this.props.form;

   validateFields((err, params) => {
       if (!err) {
            const { user, dispatch } = this.props;

            dispatch(actions.addDevice(params)).then((response)=>{
                  console.log(response);
            })
       }
    });
}
```

**actions.addDevice**

```
function addDevice(params){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let { authentication } = getState();
        dispatch(request({}));

        return service.addDevice(params, authentication.user.access_token)
            .then(
                response => {
                    if(response.status === 201) {
                        dispatch(success(response.data));
                    }
                    return response;
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            )
    }

    function request(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_REQUEST, response } }
    function success(response) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_SUCCESS, response } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: constants.ADD_DEVICE_FAILURE, error } }
}
```